# Should I make multiple Ajax requests or combine into one

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am building some html reports. The user can choose to view additional data for individual elements of the report, or choose to view all additional data.

To view a single line of additional data, an Ajax request is made.

My question is that if a user clicks "View all additional data", should I make 20 or so asynchronous Ajax calls, or just make a single Ajax call that might take a little longer.

Aside from usability, are there any best practices as far as making lots of smaller Ajax requests vs one larger one?

Answer (score 1):

I would say normally you would want to make one call. Your sending a request to the server - while you are there - just get all the data you need before coming back. Depending on the situation you could always cache some of the data (by storing in a variable) - to limit the amount of information you are retrieving.